Jenkins Resource Root URL not working (404) with Project-based matrix auth
Running Jenkins on dedicated machine, with SSL provided by Haproxy.
Jenkins runs inside internal network, with URL https://jenkins.company.com , https://jenkins-static.company.com is set up to point to the same machine.
Haproxy settings as from jenkins tutorial (disabling haproxy and switching to direct HTTP does not solve the issue).
When setting up Resource Root URL using "Manage Jenkins >> System", all artifacts URL are converted to https://jenkins-static.company.com/static-files/TOKEN/FILE_PATH but trying to open the link always leads to "Oops!" 404 page.
I was unable to find any related information in the logs.
To make Resource URL work I had to add "Job/Read" permission to "Authenticated Users" in global settings for Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy. But this breaks the security of my Jenkins instance, so this solution can't be applied.
